# Use Lightning Component Attribute to Pass URL via Variable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, aura-attribute, rss

I am trying to create an RSS feed Lightning component. I am able to successfully setup the the component to read the URL for the feed if I hard code it into the component. Since I want an admin to be able to update the RSS feed or have the component serve multiple use cases, I would like to be able to use the Design page within the component to pass the URL via a attribute. This is what I have so far:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="URL" type="String" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="NumberOfFeedItems" type="Integer" access="global"/> 
    <div class="slds-box" style="padding: 1.0rem; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div aura:id="divSection" class="slds-section">   
           <h3 class="slds-section__title" onclick="{!c.sectionClicked}">
               <button aria-controls="expando-unique-id" aria-expanded="false" class="slds-button slds-section__title-action">
                    <lightning:icon aura:id="rightIcon" class="section-icon slds-hide" iconName="utility:chevronright" size="xx-small" alternativeText="hide section"/>
                    <lightning:icon aura:id="downIcon" class="section-icon slds-show" iconName="utility:chevrondown" size="xx-small" alternativeText="open section"/> 
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                    <div>Security News Feed</div>   
                    <span class="slds-truncate" title="Section Title"></span>
                </button>
            </h3>
            <div aria-hidden="true" class="slds-section__content" >
                <div class="nav-content slds-p-left_large slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-right_large">
                    <LC_Rss:RSSViewer URL="{!v.URL}" includeDesc="True" includeImage="True" numberOfEntries="{!v.NumberOfFeedItems}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
<design:component label="RSS Feed">
    <design:attribute name="URL" label="Feed URL" description="RSS Feed for Component" placeholder=" " />
    <design:attribute name="NumberOfFeedItems" label="Number of Feed Items" description="Number of Feed Items to Display" placeholder="10" />
</design:component>
```

That being said - the RSS feed won't render in the component and the component returns a blank screen. Any ideas?

Comment: when it works, are you hardcoding the URL within the `LC_Rss:RSSViewer` component or as the `default` value on the `aura:attribute name="URL"` in this component markup shown above?

Comment: I am hard coding within the LC_Rss component